# How do I write a minimal MainActivity that invokes CalledActivity with a key/value pair in the Intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Write a minimal MainActivity that invokes CalledActivity with a key/value pair in the Intent. CalledActivity should show this value in a Toast. In the example below, the value is “String Passed by MAINACTIVITY”.

Show the output with the View of calledActivity and all code fragments relevant to the Intent posting process.

---

This is obviously homework, I just want a tutorial that will teach me what I need if I follow it along.  Right now I'm not understanding this.

Comment: The [Starting Another Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) training document covers everything you need to know to accomplish the task, except for `Toast`s, which you can find [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html).